# Graphics drawstring UTF8 Chinese Characters

Tags: c#, utf-8, fonts

Preface:  We sell machines that tell you the quality of the air.  We have a touch screen display that we recently upgraded to support Chinese.  I wrote a C# application that connects to the device serially and attempts to draw the screen so users can connect to their device remotely and control it.  This works great until you put the device into Chinese, then my C# app draws all the symbols as their ASCII equivalent (not Chinese symbols).

I use the `Graphics` library to do all my drawing, in which I call the `DrawString` method to draw text on the screen.  I have a picturebox in which I am doing the graphics drawing on.  How do I draw the Chinese correctly?

Code:

```
private Bitmap image;
private Color gForeColor;
private Color gBackColor;
private Font gFont;
private int gTextsize;
private int gLineSize;
private StringFormat gTextAlign;

private void Initialize()
{
    gForeColor = Color.Black;
    gTextsize = 14;
    gLineSize = 1;
    gFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", gTextsize, FontStyle.Regular);
    gTextAlign = new StringFormat();
    gTextAlign.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    gTextAlign.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
    gTextAlign.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;
    image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
}

private void DrawText(string Text, int X1, int Y1)
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(gForeColor); //Foreground
        SolidBrush bb = new SolidBrush(gBackColor); //Background

        g.DrawString(Text, gFont, sb, X1, Y1, gTextAlign);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();   //refresh

        gTextAlign.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;    //horizontal alignment reverts to Left after a text display command is issued
    }
}
```

I tried adding this line
`Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Text));` To try and decode the text properly but now it prints '??????' instead of the ASCII letters or Chinese symbols.

Example:

**English**

[image: English]

**Chinese**

[image: Chinese]

Edit:  It seems the `ReadExisting()` from the SerialPort was converting all the bytes into '??????'. I stopped using ReadExisting and switched to Read which keeps the raw bytes. So now I'm getting the correct ASCII, but still not Chinese. I re-added my line `Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Text));` and now I'm getting Chinese with some extra symbols that aren't correct. Am I using the wrong encoding?

[image]

Comment: Unless wrting to a printer TextRenderer.DrawText is recommended over Graphics.DrawString

Comment: This: `Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Text));` is clearly wrong. Let the Encoding stuff rest, you don't need it here. Use Microsoft YaHei UI or Segoe UI (the latter will fall-back to the former). As TaW suggested, use `TextRenderer.DrawText()`. You (really) need to dispose of the Brushes.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't draw to a Bitmap but on the PictureBox surface. So, use your `pictureBox1.Paint` event to draw your strings (no Bitmap).

Comment: It seems the `ReadExisting()` was converting all the bytes into '??????'.  I stopped using `ReadExisting` and switched to `Read` which keeps the raw bytes.  So now I'm getting the correct ASCII, but still not Chinese.  I re-added my line `Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Text));` and now I'm getting Chinese with some extra symbols that aren't correct.  Am I using the wrong encoding?

Comment: Of course Chinese cannot be encoded in ASCII. If you're getting bytes from a source (which you didn't mention before), it depends on what encoding was used on the sender side. If `Encoding.Default` was used then you need to use the same encoding on the receiver side (and `Encoding.Default` in the receiver side may not be the same encoding, or it is, you're the only one that knows it). If it is (your `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is the same as the sender's), use `Encoding.Default.GetString([bytes])`. Otherwise, use `Encoding.GetEncoding()`,specifying the CodePage used by the sender.

Comment: Or, if you're sure that UTF8 was used by the sender to turn a string into bytes, just `Encoding.UTF8.GetString([bytes])`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, it's now working properly.  Converting the bytes to ascii then to utf8 was doing something funky.  Just encoding the bytes to UTF8 fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you can use `Microsoft Sans Serif` with Chinese? I highly doubt.

Comment: Good point, now that I think about it I doubt it does too.  Do you have a font to recommend?

Comment: I can't really recommend any font, as I haven't used anything with Chinese, but I think it wouldn't be hard to find some font that can be used with any language, or at least, implement some function that will decide which font to use depending on the language, for example, via ASCII table, you can calculate which symbol range is used in the word and determine approximately if it's some Asian language, and then change the used font in the runtime.